# Как может такая безобидная функция всё ломать?

Tags: c

Как может такая безобидная функция всё ломать?

```
void strout(char s[],int st,int en){
  for(int i = st+1;st<en;i++)
    putchar(s[i]);
};
```

Comment: Это **очень** небезобидная функция. Если длина передана неправильно, она залезет в неизвестную область. И у функции нет никакой возможности проверить правильность данных.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы увеличиваете в цикле `i`, а условие выхода из цикла у вас - `st<en`
Таким образом у вас получается бесконечное увеличение `i` и попытка напечатать мусор.

```
void strout(char s[],int st,int en){
   for(int i = st+1;st<en;i++)
   putchar(s[i]);
};
```

Нужно так:

```
void strout(char s[],int st,int en){
   for(int i = st+1;i<en;i++)
   putchar(s[i]);
}
```